Instagram Basic Display API does not show images in production (Error: "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.")
I am trying to implement Instagram Basic Display API in React with Express to display instagram feed images on my webpage. I followed instructions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) and deployed on VPS. The CORS is set up in Express.
However, while the images are displayed correctly on localhost and on http://VPS-IP:PORT, I get an error on the actual website: "Error fetching Instagram media: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". When I inspect Network > Responses, I get "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."
I believe I have the correct settings for my website on Meta for Developers app but something is obviously incorrect. I have spent two days trying to change settings and created a new app but the outcome is the same. To be frank, I am not sure what to do. I searched the internet for a similar error but could not resolve the issue.
